# Pointers in B Tree

Tags: c++, database, algorithm, data-structures

I read about B trees and understand their input, delete methods. I read with an introduction like this:

> When we build structures on disk, we must deal with certain realities of
>       access and transfer time:
>
> 1. Random access to disk typically requires on the order of 10-20 ms
>      access time to position the head and wait for data to come up under
>      it.
> 2. Once the head position is right, data can be transferred at rates in
>      excess of 1 million bytes/sec.
> 3. Observe, then, how total transfer times behave for different size
>      blocks (assuming a fairly fast 10 ms access time, and 1 megabyte/sec
>      transfer rate)

So, B Tree Data Structure is made for serving from disk ( which is what makes them great for Databases ). But when I tried to implement it, I hit this problem.

Normal B Tree diagrams shows pointers to child nodes which then descend down to leaves.

But *how do I make pointers on the disk*?  Is it like a file name ?

Comment: Each record, stored on disk, is the logical equiv. of a node.  Many nodes are stored in a single file.  Just keep track of where the head record is, and each record points to the offset for its children.  Just as memory is a linear resource, you may also think of the file holding your records as a linear resource.  Each record will contain a payload, and a pair of offsets to locate the children.

Comment: If each record is a node then what is the offsets ? What is a record as such , File ?? And offsets, file_names ?? Or Everything is in one big file and offset is the offset of that node location in that file ?

Comment: Just to remind you - pointer is nothing more than an address, a location of some memory chunk. This applies to files too, as they can be seen as chunks of some persistent memory...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

On-disk-pointers are `offsets` from the beginning of the file.

if your `key` points to address ***n*** then it means that

1. open the data-file
2. read ***n*** bytes but discard them *(or simply jump over them. that is called seeking. see below for how)*
3. start reading the data which is of your interest.

now, as optimizations,

1. the data file could be already open, say when your program starts; could be cached in memory of course partially.
2. rather than reading and discarding the bytes you can specifically instruct the framework to *goto* a specific location in the file. most languages have that feature. all OS do. This is called seeking. You call a method like `file.seek(1024)`. To perform the jump, the OS has to know which point in disk the data you are seeking is located. That involves some more lookup, some disk movement, but that all is done by the OS.
3. you can *start* reading data, but to know when to stop, either have fixed-width records or you can put the record-length in the first 4-bytes of your record. this makes `headers` and metadata which would grow with complexity.

what is interesting is that the pointers associated with each `key` point to `left` and `right` `nodes` there is no place for the data. so, in a textbook example like

```
struct node {
    int key;                      //this generally is the primary key of the table
    node left;
    node right;

    long offsetOfDataInDataFile;  // <----------- we need to add this line.
}
```

this way first you locate the `node` in the `tree`. then you locate the `key`. there you get the `offset` to the actual data. you goto the location in the data file and read contents.

if your table has got multiple indexes, then or each of the index in the table, one such tree would need to be maintained. the `key` of that tree would be the contents of the column which is indexed.

Comment: Are real databases too a big long file ?

Comment: yes. the *big long file* is common among most of the databases. the indexes (b-trees) are stored as separate files. what differs is the file format, index format, packing, compression, algorithm implementations, extra features etc. some databases like ms-access and sqlite pack their whole world in **one** single file. big daddies like oracle may take an unformatted (*raw*) disk and implement their own highly specialized filesystem on it.

Comment: Reading the file from the beginning to skip to the offset is a ludicrous suggestion. B-trees presume random access. You would seek to the offset. That's not an 'optimization', it's an essential part of the algorithm. Your example is about a binary tree, not a b-tree.

Comment: @EJP, seeking is not an optimization, it is essential part of the algo. Accepted. When typing the answer, I had in mind that for OP the read-and-discard approach would be easier to understand. With the `seek` approach, there is OS and h/w involved, OS consults the Disk indexes, then instructs the h/w to move head to that cylinder. OP was already reeling under the database-indexes, so I thought to keep aside the disk indexes.

Answer (score 5):

A 'pointer' in a B-tree is just an offset within the file that you can seek to. Or if you're going to have fixed block sizes it might be a block *number,* that you multiply by the block size before seeking.